# Remove Dollar sign when entering at Input field after clicking outside need to show Dollar sign in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I'm looking to automatically remove dollar sign when I am entering value and add dollar sign on clicking outside the text box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a solution, Hope this helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var inputval = $('#myinput').val();
inputval = '$' + inputval
$('#myinput').val(inputval);
$("#myinput").on('focus', function() {

var temp = $(this).val().replace('$', '');
$(this).val(temp);
});

$("#myinput").on('blur', function() {

var temp = '$' + $(this).val();
$(this).val(temp);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myinput" />
```

P.S: I tried to use `prepend()` on  textbox `blur` but that seems to be deprecated in the version of jquery that i am referring.

Comment: :/ wish someone could come up with solid reason to give negative voting to a required working solution than just click 'vote down' for fun.